# Infinite population mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, statistical-inference

When reading about the central limit theorem, the concept of infinite population mean arises.How can a population mean be infinite?

Comment: A population mean can be infinite quite easily, although it does require whatever value you're computing the mean of to be unbounded, obviously.  What's the context here?

Comment: The central limit theorem is about the behaviour of the mean of $n$ independent random variables as $n$ increases without limit.  But $n$ remains finite.  For example, you could imagine throwing a fair die an arbitrarily large number of times and considering the distribution of the average of the throws and how close it is likely to be to $3.5$.

Comment: You should read "infinite-population mean", not "infinite population-mean" !

Answer (score 1):

**Two examples of random variables $Y$ with 'infinite' $E(Y).$**

1)  Let $X$ be geometric with $P(X = i) = 1/2^i,$ for $ i = 1, 2, \dots.$
Then let $Y = 2^X.$ If you try to find $E(Y)$ you get
an infinite sum with all terms equal to 1.

2) Let $X \sim T(1),$ Student's t distribution with one
degree of freedom. Then let $Y = |X|.$

Very roughly speaking, the tails need to be 'fat' enough
that $\sum |x|f(x)$ or $\int |x|f(x)\,dx$ (taken over all values)
is infinite, but not so fat as to prevent 
$\sum f(x) = 1$ or $\int f(x)\,dx = 1$ (or you wouldn't
have a legitimate distribution).

*Addendum:* Also, relevant to conditions for the CLT: It is possible to
have a random variable $Y$ for which $E(Y)$ exists and $Var(Y)$
does not; $T(2)$ is one example.